# MSFC "the Cluster name is not online"

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008, failovercluster

i have a microsoft 2008 failovercluster in my lab with, also, an unproductive dns server.
Unfortunately i had a hdd-crash and recover my cluster from backup.

But now, in cluster manager i see always the message *the cluster name is not online*.

In the eventviewer i have five entries with error od 1207.
i try everything and grant the permissons. but it doesn't solve the issue afer a lot of reboots.

So, is there a way to repair the dns entries or delete the dns entries and the cluster can create the entries from scratch?

Thank you for reading this
BR
Frank

Comment: This is maybe better in Server Fault

Comment: thank you - i try it also there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cluster stay offline after restore the nodes from backup and put them again into the domain. Sorry, i forgot this in my question.

I read a lot of threads and Posts from microsoft. But nothing helps.

One thrad looks promises and solved my problem finally.
[Here is the solution](http://blogs.technet.com/b/csstwplatform/archive/2010/10/15/cluster-network-name-resource-cluster-name-cannot-be-brought-online-unable-to-get-computer-object-using-guid.aspx)

BR Frank

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at the [Cluster Server Recovery Utility](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=2be7ebf0-a408-4232-9353-64aafd65306d&displaylang=en)  tool.

Is the quorum disk available?

Comment: i#ve check the link. This tool is for Server2003. Do you have experience with this tool and server 2008?

Comment: I wouldn't want you to break any existing settings but I would maybe try and run 'validate a cluster' again.

Comment: I had a similar issue in Server 2008 R2 and will look over notes to see if I can find anything.

Comment: Hey Paul, thank you for your answer. The Cluster RecoveryTool doen't solve my problem and the verification runs proper. Finally I found a solution in the web and answer my question for myself. BR Frank

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you, I'm glad you found a solution.